# Select rows with a reference to another row with some specific attribut

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

With this schema:

```
db.createCollection("test")
db.test.insertMany([
    {"id":"id1","tst":1},
    {"id":"id2","ref":"id1"}
])
```

I want to select a row with a relation to others row with specific criteria.

I found a solution, but I'm not happy with it.

1. select row with 'ref'
2. use a $lookup to join the row with referenced rows
3. use another pipeline to filter selected referenced rows
4. remove not wanted attributs

```
// Select row compatible with ref->toto="toto"
db.haystack.aggregate([
    {
        "$match":
            {
                "$expr":
                    {
                        "$and":
                            [
                                {"$cond": {"if": "$ref", "then": 1, "else": 0}}
                            ]
                    }
            }
    },
    {
        "$lookup":
            {
                "from": "haystack",
                "let":
                    {
                        "ref": "$ref"
                    },
                "pipeline": [
                    {
                        "$match":
                            {
                                "$expr":
                                    {
                                        "$and":
                                            [
                                                {"$eq": ["$id", "$$ref"]},
                                                {"$eq": ["$toto", "toto"]}
                                            ]
                                    }
                            }
                    },
                ],
                "as": "_ref"
            }
    },
    {
        "$match":
            {
                "_ref":
                    {
                        "$ne": []
                    }
            }
    },
    {"$project": {"_ref": 0}}

])
```

Can you propose a better solution?

Comment: what is the expected result as per your document and what is the `todo` condition i can not see that field in inserted document.

Comment: Select only rows compatible with ref->toto=="toto"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` to check `ref` field is exists true
- `$lookup` with same collection and pass `ref` as localfield and `id` as foreignfield
- `$match` `"_ref.toto"` is `toto`
- `$unset` to remove `_ref` field

```
db.haystack.aggregate([
  { $match: { ref: { $exists: true } } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "haystack",
      localField: "ref",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "_ref"
    }
  },
  { $match: { "_ref.toto": "toto" } },
  { $unset: "_ref" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nIluXdsktO-)